# Is there any advantage or disadvantage for function expressions inside fuction declaration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Often I see in JavaScript codes stuff similar to the following:

```
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

numbers.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
})
```

While this is OK for understanding, you can also write the code in the following way:

```
function myFunction(item) {
    console.log(item);
}
numbers.forEach(myFunction);
```

sometimes I see more complicated examples. where declarations
 are mixed with a complicated program control, for example:

```
function readStreamAsJSON(stream, callback) {
  var data = "";
  stream.on("data", function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  stream.on("end", function() {
    var result, error;
    try { result = JSON.parse(data); }
    catch (e) { error = e; }
    callback(error, result);
  });
  stream.on("error", function(error) {
    callback(error);
  });
}
// taken from http://eloquentjavascript.net/21_skillsharing.html
```

Besides being shorter on sparing variable is there an advantage for writing my JS code in a way that mixes control of functions with so many definitions?

- I am not sure the title of the question is the right one. Also note, I realize this question can be closed as opinion based question. However, I don't care about opinions like "the first way is more readable than the other". I want to know if there is a technical difference (like for example with the performance case  of `forEach` vs `for loop`).

Comment: I fail to see why this is so markedly down-voted. Maybe I'm misreading the question, but I see a perfectly legitimate question, which may not be readily answered with searching, and which is clear enough (much clearer than some).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're effectively asking if there's any particular reason that you can't write this:

```
function readStreamAsJSON(stream, callback) {
  var data = "";
  stream.on("data", function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  stream.on("end", function() {
    var result, error;
    try { result = JSON.parse(data); }
    catch (e) { error = e; }
    callback(error, result);
  });
  stream.on("error", function(error) {
    callback(error);
  });
}
```

as

```
function readStreamAsJSON(stream, callback) {
  function dataHandler(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  }
  function endHandler() {
    var result, error;
    try { result = JSON.parse(data); }
    catch (e) { error = e; }
    callback(error, result);
  }
  function errorHandler(error) {
    callback(error);
  }
  var data = "";
  stream.on("data", dataHandler);
  stream.on("end", endHandler);
  stream.on("error", errorHandler);
}
```

E.g., declaring the functions separately from using them.

The answer is no, there isn't, provided you keep them in the same scope as I have above. While there are small technical differences between the two, they end up running the same way. You're free to write whichever you prefer.

Note my point about scope, though. This would **NOT** be the same:

```
// NOT THE SAME, WILL NOT WORK
function streamDataHandler(chunk) {
  data += chunk;
}
function streamEndHandler() {
  var result, error;
  try { result = JSON.parse(data); }
  catch (e) { error = e; }
  callback(error, result);
}
function streamErrorHandler(error) {
  callback(error);
}
function readStreamAsJSON(stream, callback) {
  var data = "";
  stream.on("data", streamDataHandler);
  stream.on("end", streamEndHandler);
  stream.on("error", streamErrorHandler);
}
```

The reason that won't work is that you'll have only one version of those functions, and they won't close over the `data` and `callback` values passed into `readStreamAsJSON`.

Also note that function *declarations* must be at global scope or at the top level of a function. ES2015 enables function *statements* (which look identical to function declarations) in some other places, but the rules are complex and not yet reliable across JavaScript engines. I'd suggest sticking to declarations at the top level of the function, and for everything else using function *expressions*.

---

Brief bit of terminology: There is no function *declaration* in this code at all:

```
numbers.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
})
```

That's a function *expression*. The semantics are different (declarations happen at a different time, and have different rules).

Comment: Thank you for bothering an answering my question

Comment: @Oz123: Happy to, glad that helped. I really don't understand the way the question was received by the community.

Comment: Maybe because I titled it so badly ? I am doing baby steps in JS. But I also knew I am entering a mine field. You saw my warning. Sometime SO community is harsh (I don't know what is so wrong in having opinions, as long as arguments are not ad huminem and not starting a flame war).

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations create a variable. This is specially relevant in global scope:

```js
function myFunction() {}
[4, 9, 16, 25].forEach(myFunction);
// ...
console.log(myFunction); // The scope has been polluted
```

And be aware of function expressions inside loops:

```js
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i)
  els[i].addEventListener('click', function() { /* ... */ });
```

The code looks nice, but at each iteration of the loop you create a new copy of the function.

This is usually undesirable (unless you want the function to access the value of the iterated variable at that step, assuming it was declared with `let` or `const`), so I would use

```js
function listener() { /* ... */ }
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i)
  els[i].addEventListener('click', listener);
```